# How to make a Sum of values in a list for Charts? [ SOLVED ]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an `MVC.NET` application and I need help for one thing.

I need to get some data from my database to draw charts.

All is good but I need to make a sum of valor in the list but I don't know how to do that.

At the moment, I can only get the number of entries for the Fuel Value and I know that it comes from repartitions.Add(list.Count *)

So my Question is : How can I do the sum of the valor of the list , instead of the count?

```
public ActionResult Conso()
{
    var veh = from s in db.Fuel
              select s;
    var list = veh.ToList();

    List<int> repartitions = new List<int>();

    var comp = list.Select(x => x.VehicleId).Distinct();
    foreach (var item in comp)
    {
        repartitions.Add(list.Count(x => x.VehicleId == item));
    }
    var rep   = repartitions;
    ViewBag.COMP = comp;
    ViewBag.REP = repartitions.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is "sum of valor"?

Comment: `Sum(..)` instead of `Count(..)` ??

Comment: @Nellio What to sum?

Comment: Oh , i just checked it , Values instead of Valor , i'll change it ^^ ( French ppl btw you know .. :') )

Comment: @TaW I already tried it but , i have a error of lambda expression and "impossible to convert Bool in Long? "

Comment: @RamAnugandula I want to make a sum of the values of the list . In fact , it's just a sum of values instead of counting them but i'm really blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the count of filtered records then you can use [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
repartitions.Add(list.where(x => x.VehicleId == item).Count());
```

for SUM:

```
 repartitions.Add(list.where(x => x.VehicleId == item).Sum(x => x.columnName));
```

Comment: Got it , It worked ! I need also to change the type of the list in that :   List<double?> repartitions = new List<double?>();